# How to put CollectionAttribute<A, B> into collection like List<B> when retrieving A with Criteria API?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, criteria-api

We have an object that works as the DTO and is returned by the method using criteria API:

```
public class ServiceMobileData {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String image;

    private List<String> prefixes;
    private int categoryId;
    private boolean available;
    private boolean additionalFields;
    private boolean multiFields;

    public ServiceMobileData(int id, String name, String image, int categoryId, boolean available,
                             boolean additionalFields, boolean multiFields, List<String> prefixes) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
        this.available = available;
        this.additionalFields = additionalFields;
        this.multiFields = multiFields;
        this.prefixes = prefixes;
    }
...}
```

please note         `private List<String> prefixes;`

We have two entities:

```
public class ServiceEntity {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String name;
..

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "service")
    private Collection<ServicePrefixEntity> servicePrefixes;
    
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "service_prefixes")
public class ServicePrefixEntity {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "service_id")
    private ServiceEntity service;
..
    @Column(name = "validation_prefix")
    private String validationPrefix;

}
```

With Criteria API I retrieve the columns from the `ServiceEntity` like that:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<ServiceMobileData> c = cb.createQuery(ServiceMobileData.class);
        Root<ServiceEntity> serviceRoot = c.from(ServiceEntity.class);
        c.multiselect(serviceRoot.get(ServiceEntity_.id),
                serviceRoot.get(ServiceEntity_.name),
...
        );
TypedQuery<ServiceMobileData> q = em.createQuery(c);
return q.getResultList();
```

Currently in multiselect() there is no query to retrieve the collection of `ServiceEntityPrefix`, as adding in the corresponding last position of `multiselect` wouldn't work. What I should do to include `serviceRoot.get(ServiceEntity_.servicePrefixes)` to multiselect? I'd like to extract only one `String` parameter (namely `validationPrefix`) from the `ServicePrefixEntity` and pass a collection of them to the DTO object during the     `return q.getResultList();`, should I add this entity to join too? And how I can put those values into collection? Is it ever possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it was resolved, but not yet as I really wanted that with putting the collection into the `multiselect()` and then to the constructor.

1. add the subquery

   ```
   Subquery<String> prefixSubquery = c.subquery(String.class);
   Root<ServicePrefixEntity> prefixRoot = 
   prefixSubquery.from(ServicePrefixEntity.class);
   ```

   `prefixSubquery.select(prefixRoot.get(ServicePrefixEntity_.validationPrefix));`
   `prefixSubquery.where(cb.equal(prefixRoot.get(ServicePrefixEntity_.serviceId),serviceRoot.get(ServiceEntity_.id)));`
2. put its' output as a separate parameter into mulstiselect and adjust the returned object type constructor accordingly:

   ```
       c.multiselect(serviceRoot.get(ServiceEntity_.id),
                serviceRoot.get(ServiceEntity_.name),
   ```

   ...
   prefixSubquery.getSelection()
   );

and

```
 public ServiceMobileData(int id, String name, ... String mask) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
...
        this.mask = mask;
    }
```

What I still missing is how it is possible to instantiate subquery like that:

```
Subquery<String> prefixSubquery = c.subquery(List.class, String.class);
```

i.e. to put the result being saved to the objects collection